# Is $\mathbb{R}$ an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: metric-spaces

If we write $B(0,\infty)$ as the open ball then $\mathbb{R}$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it correct?

Comment: The radius of a ball should be a positive real number.

Comment: However, using the standard bounded metric $\hat{d}(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$, one does have that $\mathbb R = B_{\hat{d}}(0,2)$. This metric induces the same topology on $\mathbb R$ as the usual euclidean metric $d$. So $\mathbb R$ is an open ball in the metric space $(\mathbb R,\hat{d})$. Moral: you must specify a metric to talk about balls (though I understand your implicit metric).

Comment: yes, the metric is the usual euclidean metric i.e., distance between two points in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is it true that if two metrics are topologically equivalent then then an open ball w.r.t one metric is also an open ball w.r.t another metric and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, balls have finite radius. It is an open set however.

Comment: It is also closed.

Comment: That's usually what the word "no" means.  A ball has two determining features:  a center point, and a radius distance.  The radius is usually a positive real number.  I don't know of any text or person who allows the radius to be infinite.  I suppose one *could* but than one will have to *always* make specifications for finite balls and I can't see anything gained in making the reals a ball.  What you *can't* (definitely *never*) is define a ball with zero radius.  That would be the empty set and it'd make every set open.